# How to display popover using Segue to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I try to display **UITableViewController** as a popover.
I defined segue as it is on image below.

[image]

My constant with SegueIdentifier:

```
NSString *const PLDetailsAutocompleteResultSegueIdentifier = @"AutocompleteResult";
```

in the code i perform segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:PLDetailsAutocompleteResultSegueIdentifier sender:nil];
```

and prepare it:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:PLDetailsAutocompleteResultSegueIdentifier]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**The question is:**

How to get that popover controller and prepare it before display with `UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp` and with `CGSizeMake(320.0, 320.0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:PLDetailsAutocompleteResultSegueIdentifier]) {

           YourViewController *yourObject = [segue destinationViewController];
           yourObject.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 320.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this method been called.

Comment: it is working for me. http://i.imgur.com/HKZUmoW.png and http://i.imgur.com/jxtCQVC.png

Comment: ok, but it must works on iPhone. i forgot to mention about it. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67847/discussion-between-dheeraj-singh-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).